# Sorting with branching if else statement

Tags: java

I keep getting the incorrect output on 1/3. The desired output is 123 when I enter 132 or 231 I get it. When I enter 321 the output is 132, what am I missing here?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Proj3 {
    private static int min;
    private static int max;
    private static int mid;

    public static void main (String[] args){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner( System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter three whole numbers <integers> to be sorted");
        int n1 = keyboard.nextInt();
        int n2 = keyboard.nextInt();
        int n3 = keyboard.nextInt();

        if (n1 <= n2 && n1 <= n3){
            min = n1;

            if (n2 <= n3){
                mid = n2;
                max = n3;
            } else{
                mid = n3;
                max = n2;
            }
        }
        else if(n2 <= n3){
            min = n3;
            mid = n1;
            max = n2;
        }else{
            min = n3;
            mid = n1;
            max = n2;
        }
        System.out.println("Here are the three numbers sorted:"+min+""+mid+""+max+"");
    }
}
```

Comment: Tracing your code in a debugger might help you visualize what is happening in your code, and the mistake will be apparent to you.

Comment: Or pen and paper to see what's wrong with your logic.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a branching if, you could just use `Math.min` and `Math.max` to get the minimum and maximum numbers(the middle one would be the only number left)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a if-branch. For the Input 321 you run in the else block and that causes your ouput. Try to figure out which case you forgot and add it as another else if case.

**EDIT:**
If n1 > n2 it remains unclear whether it's smaller or bigger than n3.

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution my appreciation for those that helped me think through this @ZouZou , @ROT13, @Laf.

```
else if(n2 >= n3 && n2 <= n1){
       max = n1;
       mid = n2;
       min = n3;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could to change your code a little bit and use an array. Read-in values from a scanner and then add them to an array. From an array, you can use the `.sort()` method that will automatically put the numbers in order.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // Starts scanner
    int[] numbers = new int[3]; // Sets length to 3

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) // Loops length
{
    System.out.println("Please enter number"); // Asks for input
    numbers[i] = input.nextInt(); // Adds to array
}
```

After the values are sorted you can call the `.sort()` method on the `int[]` array. I hope this makes sense. You can use all your if statements, but why make it harder than it should be? Let me know if you need any help